# How to promisify nodejs child_process exec to work with es6

Tags: node.js, exec, child-process, es6-promise

I have phantomjs script which takes url as in command line args and return the body html content in stdout.

When I receive html content via promise call via phantomjs script then i call parsePage() to manipulate the data via `cheerio` and then gatherNext().

```
let cmd = '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs ' + __dirname + '/phantom.js';

let child = (command) => {
    return exec(command)
        .then(result => {
            return result.stdout;
        });
};

let parsePage = (result) => {

    debug('stdout %s', result);

    var $ = cheerio.load(result); 
    // logic - page crawl data & will 've data as array of objects

   return resultArray
};   

let gatherNext = (products) => {
  debug('products %j', products);
  allProducts = allProducts.concat(products);

  if(/*not hasNextPage*/) {
  return allProducts;
  }
  else {
  return Promise.resolve(cmd + ' ' + data.productLink + '&page=' + page).then(child)// this.parse({url: `&page=${page}`})
      .then(parsePage)
      .then(gatherNext);
  }
};

debug('parsing page by page');

return Promise.resolve(cmd + ' ' + data.productLink + '&page=' + page).then(child).then(parsePage).then(gatherNext);
```

But I am not able to promisify exec function? How can i achieve this?

edit:

I've found this lib: github.com/sindresorhus/execa which resolves the promise issue but another issue i'm getting. which is for every next page (i.e, page - paginating 2, 3, 4, 5, etc) the child func promise always return old one's (first page's html content) for all next pages.. why is this happening in this case? any idea?

here's modified code for this:

```
let child = (pager) => {
        let command = cmdBase + pager;
        console.log('command: ', command);
        return execa.shell(command).then(result => {
            return result.stdout;
        });
    };
```

or, any better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but you have some extraneous close-parentheses (  `});` should be `}`; )

Comment: thanks but still not working!

Comment: i've got this lib https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa and it resolves the promise issue but another issue i'm getting. which is for every next page (i.e, paginating 2, 3, 4, 5, etc) the `child` func promise always return old one's (first page's html content) for all next pages.. why is this hapening in that case? any idea?